# req.get('host') - expressJS - same value on different hosts -?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

hi I try to get host name in node express js - 
i use:

```js
var express = require('express'),
 app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(function(req,res,next){
 
 if (req.hostname == "domain1") {
  app.get('/', function(req,res){
   res.send('Domain1 is active');
  }) else if (req.hostname == "domain2") {
  app.get('/', function(req,res){
   res.send('Doamin2 is active');
  });
  }
  
  
 } 
 next();
});

app.listen(port);
```

but its works correct only on the first host - if i change host - I have first result

any advice ?

Comment: Why not use `request.headers.host` ? Besides, I don't think there is anything useful you can do with this information. Why would you need host name of the client?

Comment: Addendum: If you need hostname of the server then this is how you can get it, `var os = require("os");
os.hostname();`

Comment: i have three different domains
if host name == 'exa.com' then #code 
else if name == 'exa1.com' then #code2 

my code works correct only for the first domain / if i change domain to other - still have information form the first one :-( where is bug ?